# Amazon.StopIntent is behaving weirdly in Alexa Skill

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

My STOPINTENT is behaving weirdly, it is giving back null in the JSON output, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. None of my previous skills ran into this issue.

```
'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
this.response.speak('Goodbye!');
this.emit(':responseReady');
```

I am still getting **There was a problem with the requested skill's response**

**JSON Input**

```
"request": {
        "type": "IntentRequest",
        "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.8e9eadd5-7018-40b0-a749-ba84ee2d44f7",
        "timestamp": "2018-01-09T01:36:44Z",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "intent": {
            "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
            "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with some unhandled states, for AMAZON.HELP and AMAZON.STOP Intent.

I got them to work by adding those HELP, STOP, CANCEL in all my handlers with different states.

Whenever using different state handlers, ensure that all handlers contain their separate AMAZON.HELP and AMAZON.STOP Intent to make them work properly.